# Windows batch file timing bug

Tags: windows, batch-file, timing

I've used %time% for timing previously - at least I think I have.  I have this weird

```
IF NOT "%1" == "" (
    echo Testing: %1
    echo Start: %time%
    sqlcmd -S MYSERVER  -i test_import_%1.sql -o "test_%1%.log"
    sleep 3
    echo End:   %time%
)
```

I run this, and it prints:

```
Testing: pm
Start: 13:29:45.30
End:   13:29:45.30
```

In this case, my sql code is failing (different reason), but I figure the sleep 3 should make the time increment by 3 at least.  Any ideas?
tx,
tff

Comment: Pause doesn't accept a parameter at all, does it?

Comment: Sorry that should have said "sleep 3"

Comment: sleep is not a batch command at all.

Comment: @GolezTrol: sleep.exe can be download from Microsoft, see http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657

Comment: @HarryJohnston Good to know. Fortunately, that turned out not to be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has something to do with (not) delayed expansion, but I don't remember how that works exactly. You can work around it by using a "subroutine" like this:

```
@echo off
if "%1" == "" (
  call :doit
)

echo done
goto :eof

:doit
echo %time%
sleep 1
echo %time%
goto :eof
```

Output:

```
C:\temp>q
19:46:36.43
19:46:37.45
done
```

The "proper" way of doing this is probably something like (from [this entry in Raymon Chen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx)):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "%1" == "" (
  echo !time!
  sleep 2
  echo !time!
)
```

---

To "see" the problem with immediate expansion, just run this (*without* `echo off`):

```
if "%1" == "" (
echo %time%
sleep 2
echo %time%
)
```

Output (on Windows 7):

```
C:\temp>if "" == "" (
echo 19:48:31.95
 sleep 2
 echo 19:48:31.95
)
19:48:31.95
19:48:31.95
```

The variables are all expanded at the same time, when the `if` is parsed.

Comment: Smart thinking. I was looking for a workaround, but couldn't find it yet. This actually makes sense, because cmd treats the whole if as a single statement, expanding all those variables at (almost) the same time.

Comment: That works!  Completely new thing to me! thanks! and thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

`Pause` doesn't accept a parameter at all. It won't fail, but it won't continue either. If all is right, you should see a prompt to press a key.

The time you get, is the time the script is started. Apparently the `%time%` environment variable is not updated during the execution of the script.

Answer (score 1):

DOS doesn't have a "sleep" function.  You need to add this to the end of your batch file (or something like this):

```
@ECHO off
TITLE Initial title
SET TITLETEXT=Sleep
:: start of script
CALL :sleep 5
:: rest of script
GOTO :END
:: Function
:sleep ARG
ECHO Pausing...
FOR /l %%a in (%~1,-1,1) do (TITLE %TITLETEXT% -- time left %%as&PING.exe -n 2 -w 1 127.0.0.1>nul)
EXIT /B 0
:END
pause
::this is EOF
```

I tested this code, it should work fine.

Comment: DOS didn't have a sleep command, and Windows doesn't have a sleep command built-in, but sleep.exe can be downloaded from Microsoft.  See http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657

Comment: Personally, I don't choose to use any of the resourse kit tools because most things I need can be done in DOS shell by itself.  Sometimes I use wget.ext, robocopy.exe, or xmlstarlet.exe but that is all.